# Maui - Editor (view/control)- how raise "completed" event?

Tags: .net-6.0, maui

In .Net Maui I am using an Editor view. I am also using codebehind as it is convenient for what I'm doing.

There is a Completed event. However, this is raised by: quote

The Completed event is raised when the user has ended input by pressing the return key on the keyboard, or by pressing the Tab key on Windows.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/editor

On Android Pixel 5 emulator the keyboard comes up
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwfF4.png)

The return key causes a newline on the Editor viewport which is actually what I want, so how do I complete the action and raise my completed event?

I must be missing something very obvious here?

Code XAML

```
      <Editor Grid.Row="1" 
              x:Name="SurveyCodes"
              FontSize="20"
              TextColor="Yellow"
              Placeholder="Enter survey codes"
              Completed="SurveyCodesCompleted"
              TextTransform="Uppercase"
              Keyboard="Default"/>
```

and code behind

```
  private void SurveyCodesCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    ...
  }
```

Comment: if there is not a DONE button on the keyboard itself you probably would need to add one in your UI

Comment: Indeed that is exactly what I did. I wonder why the done button doesn't appear or how to make it do so?

Answer (score 1):

**Update：**

Thanks for your feedback and support.

There is a known issue about this problem.

You can follow it up here: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/5730 .

Comment: Thanks for that. I was looking at the Editor control though not Entry. I tried it anyway, but no joy. However, it strikes me that you can't have both a return key and a done key at the same time?

Comment: Thanks for your patience,I have updated my answer. You can check it.